# C/C++ recvmsg() causes error 'unaligned tcache chunk detected' but recv() is successful

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, network-programming

I observe the below error when receiving UDP packets via Epoll:

```
'unaligned tcache chunk detected'
```

I've managed to locate which part of the code but it doesn't make much sense.

This is the original code:

```
while (_listen)
{
    const int count = epoll_wait(_epollFd, &events[0], MAX_SOCKETS, -1);
    assert(count != -1);

    for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
    {
        iovec iov;
        char control[1024];

        msghdr msg;

        iov.iov_base = _buffer;
        iov.iov_len = sizeof(_buffer);
        msg.msg_iov = &iov;
        msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
        msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
        msg.msg_control = &control[0];
        msg.msg_controllen = 1024;

        const int sock = events[j].data.fd;
        const int64_t n = recvmsg(sock, &msg, 0);   // This line seems to cause the problem
        // More code
    }
}
```

`_buffer` is a class member declared as: `char _buffer[65'536];`

By trial and error I narrowed the problem to this line:

```
const int64_t n = recvmsg(sock, &msg, 0);
```

So I replaced `::recvmsg()` with a call to `::recv()` and it runs successfully:

```
while (_listen)
{
    const int count = epoll_wait(_epollFd, &events[0], MAX_SOCKETS, -1);
    assert(count != -1);

    for (int j = 0; j < count; ++j)
    {
        const int sock = events[j].data.fd;
        const int64_t n = recv(sock, _buffer, sizeof(_buffer), 0);
        // More code
    }
}
```

Now the problem doesn't occur. What is causing this?

I'd like to understand why the first code doesn't work. The only memory is `_buffer` and that's not manually allocated.

(Unfortunately I cannot use a sanitize build due to the environment/build system).

Comment: Somewhere earlier in your program you caused heap corruption. Did you try googling the error message?

Comment: @Barmar Yes but there was nothing specific, just generic. They just said it means heap corruption.

Comment: It could be anywhere. This happens when `malloc()` is trying to allocate memory and it detects a problem in its heap data structures.

Comment: Try using `valgrind` to debug memory management problems.

Comment: @Barmar so the corruption might not be in the line in question, just the line in question is the one allocating memory and finds the problem?

Comment: @Barmar Unfortunately I have a Python entry point, calling C++ so it's not so easy to use.

Comment: That's correct. When you cause undefined behavior, the symptoms could happen any time later.

Comment: I think your code crashes because you forgot to set member `msg.msg_name`.

Comment: Try declaring variable `sockaddr_in addr;` and then add it to your `msg` struct with `msg.msg_name = &addr;`

Comment: @LucaPolito Just create it on the stack, uninitialized?

Comment: @LucaPolito seems it was it!!!!!

Comment: @user997112 You create it without initializing on the stack, because `recvmsg()` will initialize it for you. Glad it worked.

Comment: @LucaPolito put it as an answer. Out of curiousity, why was it a heap corruption though? Accessing null ptr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you forgot to set member `msg_name` of the struct `msg`:

```c
iovec iov;
char control[1024];
msghdr msg;

// add the following line:
sockaddr_in addr;

iov.iov_base = _buffer;
iov.iov_len = sizeof(_buffer);
msg.msg_iov = &iov;
msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
msg.msg_control = &control[0];
msg.msg_controllen = 1024;

// set the following members:
msg.msg_name = &addr;
msg.msg_namelen = sizeof(addr);

const int sock = events[j].data.fd;
const int64_t n = recvmsg(sock, &msg, 0);

// More code
```

The reason you had memory corruption is because you had undefined behavior: `recvmsg()` tried to write to pointer `msg.msg_name`, but the latter contained an uninitialized memory address, so `recvmsg()` was actually writing to an invalid location.

`recvmsg()` writes information about the host that sent the message inside `msg.msg_name`.

Comment: Thanks .........